# Setting UITextView's editable to NO always resigns FirstResponder. Can be avoided?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview, first-responder

My app basically lets you send a piece of text. When the user taps send, I would like to disable the text view which contains the text so the user can't edit it anymore as the text is being sent. It seems though that setting either enableUserInteraction or editable to NO always resigns the first responder (basically the keyboard is dismissed) which is a behavior I don't want. I want to keep the keyboard displayed. Is there anyway around this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want a keyboard to remain that...can't do anything? That's an odd UI decision, and probably won't fit the Apple UI guidelines.

Comment: @Adam I want a similar behavior to any IM or texting app. The keyboard remains on screen, all the time, unless the user specifically dismisses it. Tapping send doesn't dismiss the keyboard either. What I want to do, however, is lock the field as the message is being sent.

Comment: I'd be fairly sure/hopeful that such a behavior wouldn't get through App Review

Answer (score 2):

While I don't really understand why you think it's a good idea to keep the keyboard on screen if there's nothing to edit, you can achieve this by having a hidden `UITextField` and making that first responder.

Answer (score 1):

If the UITextView's [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextViewDelegate) method `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` returns NO, its contents will not be changed.